# Как решить задачу № 7 из Проекта Эйлера оптимизированно

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

я уже сделал решение этой задачи на Python, однако возникла проблема. На сайте самого проекта говорится, что решение должно занимать не более минуты.
Моё занимает 7.

Мне хотелось бы услышать допущенные оптимизационные ошибки и чуть-чуть утешения(

Вот мой код:

```
y = 1
counter = 0
ist = False


def is_prime(x):
    global ist
    s = 0
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            s += 1
    if s == 0:
        ist = True


while True:
    y += 1
    is_prime(y)
    if ist is True:
        ist = False
        counter += 1
    if counter == 10001:
        print(y)
        break
```

Также я нашёл чужой, уже оптимизированный код:

```
A = [1] * 1000000
A[0] = A[1] = summa = 0
for i in range(2, 1000000, 1):
    if A[i]:
        for m in range(2 * i, 1000000, i):
            A[m] = 0
        summa = summa + A[i]
    if summa == 10001:
        print(summa)
        print("Наше число " + str(i))
        break
```

P.S. Правильный ответ: 104743.

Comment: понятно, что проект эйлера вещь довольно известная, но мало кто помнит тут текст задачи номер 7

Comment: за global в некоторых местах отрывают пальцы рук по одному. Что делает строчка is_prime(y)? Проверяя число на простоту, нет необходимости делить его на все числа до самого числа.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, такого изврата, чтобы явным образом вместо `return` использовать `global` совершенно на ровном месте, я ещё, кажется, не видел ))

Comment: заменил `range(2,x)` на `range(2,math.sqrt(x)+1)` и на моей машине с 340 секунд до 1 уменьшилось (что ожидаемо)

Comment: а потом ещё в цикле поправил и теперь все выполняется за 0.23 секунды

Comment: Решето ещё быстрее будет.

Comment: на их сайте после принятия ответа можно посмотреть ответы других людей.и там можно найти сверх оптимизированные варианты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ох, посмотрел на это и решил, что нужно показать свой вариант.

```
import math

def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(x)+1), 2):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

y = 1
counter = 1

while counter != 10001:
    y += 2
    if is_prime(y):
        counter += 1

print(y)
```

время выполнения - около одной десятой секунды

Comment: `int(math.sqrt(x) + 1)` -> `math.isqrt(x) + 1`.

Comment: надоело смотреть как непросвещенные и недалекие пытаются что-то сделать)))

Comment: ну я не настолько хорошо знаю питон:) А у людей тут даже такое есть

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, там экономия какая-то смешная. Может лучше от библиотеки избавиться `int(x**0.5) + 1` )

Comment: я поставил вместо 10001 число 100001 и это все равно за 3 секунды выполняет

Comment: можно и избавиться. Но я постоянно забываю этот синтаксис

Comment: @CrazyElf, я не за экономией гоняюсь. Для `x**0.5` нет гарантий точности. Можно потерять последнее число. Для `math.sqrt(x)` гарантии есть, пока корень лезет в 53 бита. `math.isqrt` всегда считает точно. Это что-то вроде мытья рук перед едой - сразу от грязных рук не умирают, но болеют чаще.

Comment: @CrazyElf, 53 бита - мантисса `float`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Переделал проверку, да, 53 бита предел, всё сходится )

Answer (score 2):

У вас очень сложное и неоптимизораванное решение, к тому же, вы проверяете все числа, и четные, и нечетные, а простым числом является только одно четное число, это 2, все остальные четные числа можно даже не рассматривать. Кстати, глобальная переменная тут ни к чему, и `if`-ы очень сильно замедляют вашу программу, поэтому я их вообще убрал.

```py
import math

y = 3
counter = 1


def is_prime(x):
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1, 2):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    
    return True


while counter != 10001:
    if is_prime(y):
        counter += 1

    y += 2

print(y - 2)
```

Comment: Ваше решение хоть и быстрее, но почитали бы мои комментарии, его можно сделать ещё быстрее. Ваше решение у меня выполняется за 15 секунд, когда мое - доли секунды

Comment: @KoVadim у меня тоже цикл уменьшен, хотя не на столько как у вас)

Comment: не нужно проверять делимость на четные числа. Достаточно в самом начале перед цеиклом проверить делимость на 2, и потом делить только на нечетные.

Comment: @Эникейщик то есть поставить цикл с шагом 2?

Comment: да. Да и проверять можно только до квадратного корня.

Comment: Хотя не, даже на 2 проверять не надо, там же только нечетные передаются. Т.е. просто заменить for i in range(3, x // 2 + 1) на for i in range(3, x // 2 + 1, 2)

Comment: смотрите мой ответ, я там ещё лучше сделал. уменьшить в два раза и уменьшить на квадрат - совершенно разные вещи

Comment: просто программа теперь выполняется меньше чем за секунду, вот это оптимизация))) вау!

Comment: @Эникейщик аплодирую стоя! (без рофла)

Comment: @KoVadim аплодирую стоя! (без рофла)

Comment: а что тут удивляться. как мне кажется, то то, что нужно до корня считать - почти общеизвестный факт, который можно и логически вывести (если делить на число больше квадратного корня, то будут получаться числа меньше квадратного корня, а их уже прошли)

Comment: @KoVadim  я до этого почему-то не дошел своим умом, я дошел только до деления напополам (

Comment: @zolars Тут много раз подобные задачи уже обсуждали, поэтому про перебор до корня уже общее место вообще )

Comment: @CrazyElf я тут просто недавно, только познаю бытие стаковерфлольщика)

Answer (score 2):

Неоптимизированное решето Эратосфена. Деления не нужны. Размер решета тоже не подбирается оптимально: если решета не хватило, строим заново решето в два раза больше. Несмотря на всё это решето примерно в два раза быстрее любого метода с непосредственной проверкой простоты.

```
import math


def primes(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(2, math.isqrt(n)):
        if sieve[i]:
            for j in range(i * i, n, i):
                sieve[j] = False
    for i in range(2, n):
        if sieve[i]:
            yield i


def nth_prime(n):
    m = 1
    while True: 
        for i, p in enumerate(primes(m), start=1):
            if i == n:
                return p
        m *= 2


print(nth_prime(10001))


$ time python sieve.py 
104743

real    0m0.059s
user    0m0.048s
sys 0m0.008s
```